# can a threadpool(like boost) be initialized into a class constructor and used when class members are called?

Tags: multithreading, threadpool, boost-thread

Lets say I have a threadpool (example might be http://threadpool.sourceforge.net/);
And i have this code:

```
class Demigod{ 
public:
   Demigod();
   void AskObedienceFast();
   void AskObedienceSlow();
   void WorkHardGodDamn();
   ~Demigod();
private:
   ThreadPool m_PitySlaves;
   int m_Quota;
};
Demigod::Demigod() : m_PitySlaves(manyPlease) { 
}
void Demigod::WorkHardGodDamn(){ 
    //something irelevant just to annoy slaves
}
void Demigod::AskObedienceFast() { 
    for(int q=0; q<m_Quota; ++q){
       m_PitySlaves.schedule(boost::bind(&Demigod::WorkHardGodDamn, this)); 
    }
    m_PitySlaves.wait();
}
void Demigod::AskObedienceSlow() { 
    ThreadPool poorSouls;
    for(int q=0; q<m_Quota; ++q){
       poorSouls.schedule(boost::bind(&Demigod::WorkHardGodDamn, this)); 
    }
    poorSouls.wait();
}
void main(){ 
   Demigod someDude;
   for(size_t i=0; i<dontstop; ++i){ 
      someDude.AskObedienceFast();
   }
}
```

Can AskObedienceFast be faster and work in comparison with AskObedienceSlow? 
This way I can have some thread (slaves) and be ready for work anytime I ask without having to lose time making the threadpool at every call. I know I can verify the code myself, but my question is more broad, if this is not fundamentally lose performance somewhere else, like those threads in the threadpool doing some waiting process? It comes down to avoiding expensive threadpool initialization (and threads).

Comment: +1 for the hilarious inventiveness of code example, as compared to common foo, bar and baz. Next iteration will be actually reading the code and trying to understand the problem :)

Comment: thanks, a little i can do for loosing someone else time thinking trough my questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing like "waiting process". If a thread is waiting (on a condition), scheduler is simply skipping it, therefore such thread does not do anything and is not being switched in and out. As you very correctly pointed out, the most expensive task in threading is setting up the thread (though all major OSes are taking steps in minimizing it as much as possible, to keep pace with the recent multiplication of cores), closely followed by switching thread contexts. So you can see why `AskObedienceSlow` is horrible. Your temporaries should be only "cheap" structures, which take as little time as possible for construction and destruction. `ThreadPool` definitely isn't one such. Even `AskObedienceFast` won't protect you from the context switching overhead, but that's why bigger thread pools aren't always better and the best performing size is a matter of careful balancing dependent on your actual workload. Some of the best performing high load, high throughput applications are single-thread, message-passing designs for this very reason. Programming languages used for such applications (like Erlang) are explicitly threadless.

Comment: thanks for iluminating me that there is no waiting process. so a big loss of the performance can be gain by avoiding initialization, but you also carefully pointed that there is a disadvantage in having a big pool of threads as they will contex switch to often on the actual processors and downgrade performance. but ill try starting using a pool size = how many processors. ill investigate on message parsing designs as i dont have any idea. thanks

Comment: Yes number of processor cores is a good start. For *message passing* (not **paRsing** :-) and also *message loop*, you can always start with Wikipedia.